# Extract filepath from arbitrary string

Tags: c#, .net, registry, startup, boot

I've been attempting to list all filepaths for programs that start on boot. I encountered the following data

```
Rundll32.exe shell32.dll, ShellExec_RunDLL C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\Oracle\JavaUpdate.exe

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -silent
```

This data is from the registry \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run, obtained using following code

```
foreach(var valueName in registryKey.GetValueNames()){
  bootItems.Add(registryKey.GetValue(valueName);
}
```

Which solution could extract the path from both?
I've attempted to use the following regular expression and variations without any luck.

```
"^\"([^\"]*)\".*$"
```

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Multiple different regexes, none which I've managed to get working.

Comment: show the code that returned those strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they only ever look like that then this regex will do the job:

```
\b.:\\.+?.exe\b
```

It matches any character followed by a colon and a slash,followed by any text that then ends with .exe where the start/end is either a word break or a start/end of line.